# matlab version doesn't support some functions

Tags: matlab

Undefined function '[extractHOGFeatures](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/extracthogfeatures.html)' and am using Matlab R2016a version , Is  'extractHOGFeatures' included in this version or not ? if yes how can i include ? 
if not in which version and how can i use it ?

Comment: What is the complete and exact error message? Apparently you don't have **Computer Vision System Toolbox** .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one could see in the documentation of [`extractHOGFeatures()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/extracthogfeatures.html) it was introduced in MATLAB R2013b:

[image: MATLAB's extractHOGFeatures Documentation]

This is a great feature in the documentation of any MATLAB's function.

If you still don't have access to it, probably it's because the function is part of [Computer Vision System Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/index.html) which requires a license you may not have.